# How to include js.erb file in view folder

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a JavaScript file to use with a view. There needs to be Ruby code in it, and I need to do `render` in Ruby, so I understand that I can't put the JavaScript file in the asset pipeline. I can put it in the same view folder as the `.html.erb` file.

How do I include the JavaScript file, or use that JavaScript file for that view file? I tried `javascript_include_tag` in my view (that uses the asset pipeline apparently), using script `src="myfile.js"` for the `myfile.js.erb` file (but it can't find `myfile.js`), and names my `js.erb` file (`users.js.erb`) the same as my `.html.erb` file (`users.html.erb`), but all to no avail.

Comment: where is your js file and what is your javascript_include_tag looked like?

Comment: If you want to access the js files outside of the asset pipeline, you have to put in public folder

Comment: As an alternative, you can use obtrusive Javascript in layout or page erb file: include <script> tags and use ruby embedded code, but the way you **want** to include and use .js files is not the rails way.

The rails way would be to pass any data between your js side and server's side by data- parameters of html elements. SS=uch approach will result in more cleaner and DRYer code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

javascript_include_tag won't work js.erb declared in the view folder itself. There are three different ways you can have the javascript.

1] Write the code in the view, i.e., in the html.erb itself.

2] Create js file in public/javascripts folder and include it using javascript_include_tag.

3] In case you want to make the request as Ajax:

- Create the js.erb in the view folder itself with the same name as that of the action.
- In the view where some form is created which will be calling this action, make the request using `:remote => true`.
- In the called action, use code as follows:

  ```
  def action
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
  ```

Comment: I'd really appreciate if you put some examples under each step with file names, i.e.: views/model_name/action.js.erb: [code example].

Answer (score 2):

you can do this by

```
render :partial => "myfile"
```

you have to keep your file in controller's view directory with name `_myfile.js.erb`

Now you can write your own code (js,ruby) here and probably can separate out js with javascript_include_tag to avail asset pipline

This file will be first rendered by erb engine and then as javascript.

Comment: What do you mean by "separate out js with javascript_include_tag to avail asset pipline" ?