# Rails: "null" instead of an array with 3 elements when trying to use ruby array in javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have this code-snippet:

in my app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require harddisk
//= require rails-ujs
//= require_tree .
```

in my app/assets/javascripts/harddisk.js.erb

```
  var harddisk_locations = [<%= raw @harddisk_locations.to_json %>];
  console.log(harddisk_locations);
```

in my app/models/harddisk.rb

```
@harddisk_locations = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
```

But for some reason on the harddisk page in browser console

@harddisk_locations is null instead of an array with 3 elements.

Why is it so and how to fix?

It doesn't help if I move the

> @harddisk_locations = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];

from harddisk-model into harddisks_controller.rb

Comment: Try moving the file `harddisk.js.erb` in views: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18437282/how-to-include-js-erb-file-in-view-folder and also `@harddisk_locations` in controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be defining them to a global variable instead of an instance variable. You can change your model code to:

```
HD_LOCATIONS = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

and in you JS file:

```
var harddisk_locations = [<%= raw Harddisk::HD_LOCATIONS.to_json %>];
```

You can read more about variable types here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_variables.htm

Comment: then I get an error: "uninitialized constant ERB::HD_LOCATIONS"

Comment: I have updated my code. Could you please try it once and in case it throws an error, paste the exception stack?